# Как напечатать текст с textBox?

Tags: winforms

У меня есть база данных с которой я печатаю определённую информацию, а мне еще нужно с textBox печатать информацию,как это реализовать? Скажите пожалуйста

Comment: Печать куда вы хотите?

Comment: в Word если я правильно понял)